# Inserting multiple rows into a table with the same foreign key in column1 & different values for column2

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, mydbr

I use myDBR to create reports for my database and I have a form for one report where I can add a new **Event** with multiple **DesignTypes** for each Event.

I have 3 tables: **Events** (*EventID, Event, URL*), **DesignType** (*DesignTypeID, DesignType*), and **DesignTypeXEvents** (*DesignTypeXEventID, EventID, DesignTypeID*).

My form has checkboxes for the **DesignTypes**, which should insert the *EventID* and *DesignTypeID* into the table **DesignTypeXEvents**. But if I select more than one Design Type, I get an error that says **Subquery returns more than 1 row**. Is there a way that I can make *EventID* duplicate itself into the other rows if I select more than one design type?

Here's my code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_DBR_events_create`(
    inEvent varchar(70),
    inEventURL varchar(70),
    inDesignType text
    )
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Events (Event, URL)
    VALUES (inEvent, inURL);

    set @vSQL = concat('insert into DesignTypeXEvents (EventID, 
    DesignTypeID) values ((SELECT MAX(EventID) FROM Events),
    (select DesignTypeID from DesignTypes where DesignTypeID in
    (', inDesignType, ')))');
    prepare stmt from @vSQL;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
```

If I don't include the *EventID*, this code works great & inserts the proper *DesignTypeID*'s into multiple rows, but of course I need the *EventID*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` rather than `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`.

```
set @vSQL = concat('
    INSERT INTO DesignTypeXEvents (EventID, DesignTypeID)
    SELECT MaxEvent, DesignTypeID
    FROM (SELECT MAX(EventID) MaxEvent FROM Events) m
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DesignTypeID FROM DesignTypes WHERE DesignTypeID IN (', inDesignType, ')) d');
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying to find out why it wasn't working for hours. There are just some small things I changed towards the end of your code (please edit in your entry & I'll accept it): **after "CROSS JOIN"** `(SELECT DesignTypeID FROM DesignTypes WHERE DesignTypeID IN (', inDesignType, ')) d');`